# Doing a generic <sql:query> in Grails

Tags: jsp, grails

This is a generic way to select data from a table and show the results in an HTML table using JSP taglibs.  What is the generic way to do this in Grails?  That is, take a few lines of SQL and generate an HTML table from scratch in Grails, including the column names as headers.

```
<sql:query var="results" dataSource="${dsource}">
    select * from foo
</sql:query>
(# of rows: ${results.rowCount})
<table border="1">
    <!-- column headers -->
    <tr bgcolor=cyan>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${results.columnNames}">
            <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <!-- column data -->
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.rowsByIndex}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Why? If foo is a domain class the default scaffold list view will provide what you want (for 5 columns) with pagination and sorting by column.

Comment: I obviously gave a trivial SQL example.  A real example would contain 2 or 3 tables and a <b>where</b> clause.

Comment: If you got it fixed/answered at your own, you're just free to post your own answer here and accept it :)

Comment: I have done that in the past.  Would be better to have a great answer a d give someone 25 points.

Answer (score 2):

This question could be rephrased as, how do I write code like a naive ASP.NET developer?
(Not all ASP.NET developers are naive, some can be quite good)

1. Any static method is available to you in  a gsp page.  You can use any MyDomain.findBy, list(), count you want from page scope.
2. You could also use a criteria query MyDomain.createCriteria()
   You can then pass the result to a taglib.

   But all of this seems to violate MVC principles.  Your view should just be a view....

What you asked really isn't idomatic to a grails application.  I realize it is commonplace in the Microsoft world, execute a query, pass it to a datagrid....But there is no direct analouge in Grails and probably for good reason

Answer (score 0):

You could use the taglib as described.  You just need to make Grails aware of it.